# AWS CloudFormation AttributeType for DynamoDb Boolean and List data types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use AWS CloudFormation for creating an AWS DynamoDB table,
I am confused as to what to specify for a Boolean data type in the table,
in the template file.

**My data on the table shows as type Boolean -**

[image]

**Also got a List type data -**
[image]

**But on the Doc it shows it has only 3 types to specify -**

[image]

**I am following this CloudFormation ref doc -**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to use it as an index? If not you dont need those columns  there, even your template will fails that saying you have a column that not used in any indexes. Because Dynamo is [schemaless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.CreateTable.html). Unless you can use `BOOL` [type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html) as the data type.

Comment: So I don't need to specify all the fields while creating the table using CloudFormation? Just the Primary Key and Indexes?

Comment: yes, rest of the columns will get created when u insert the data

Comment: All attributes specified in the DyanmoDB table definition must be used in the Table's Key or key of an index. Only string, number and binary types can be used in a  key. Therefore only these three types can be specified.

Answer (score 2):

Would recommend the following for the Boolean Field for eg: IsActive:
(1) IsActive : {string} - "true/false" or "yes/no"
(2) IsActive : {number} - 1 -true/yes and 0 -false/no.

The AttributeType can be {string/number/Binary} only.

Answer (score 0):

`BOOL` *is* a valid data type for DynamoDB; but not for primary key attributes unfortunately. One reason for this is likely the fact that a partition key of only two possible values (`true` and `false`) does not make partitioning effective for large collections of data.

Official notes on this can be found here in AWS' documentation:
[Core Components of Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey)

Specifically:

> Each primary key attribute must be a scalar (meaning that it can hold only a single value). The only data types allowed for primary key attributes are string, number, or binary. There are no such restrictions for other, non-key attributes.